# Rust: specify template arguments during "use ... as" import

Tags: rust

I'm trying to specify a template parameter of an imported class, so that I don't need to specify it each time I want to use it. Something like this:

```
use self::binary_heap_plus::BinaryHeap<T,MinComparator> as BinaryMinHeap<T>;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes it is possible like following:

```
pub type CustomResult<T> = Result<T, MyError>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError {
    MyError1,
}

fn result_returner(prm: i32) -> CustomResult<i32> {
    if prm == 1 {
        Ok(5)
    } else {
        Err(MyError::MyError1)
    }
}
```

And also you can make such like type name changings on import as well:

```
use std::collections::HashMap as CustomNamedMap;

fn main() {
    let mut my_map = CustomNamedMap::new();
    my_map.insert(1, 2);

    println!("Value: {:?}", my_map[&1]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8eca997ab5131727f4f13623331960a4)

Comment: Thanks, the line I ended up with was
`type BinaryMinHeap<T> = binary_heap_plus::BinaryHeap<T, binary_heap_plus::MinComparator>;`. I guess the answer is the `type` is more powerful than `use`.